# Parsing through this with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I get the following from a url (get requests with python module request):

```
{"AMU":"PAR","nombres":"158612","id":"stacks"}
```

How would I get python to print just the values for example, I want it to print "stacks" or "158612"

I have tried:

```
soup.find['id']
```

and:

```
soup.find("AMU": "PAR")["nombres"]
```

Comment: If it's just a dict, do `x['nombres']` or `x['id']`

Comment: You don't need beautifulsoup for that, convert it to python's dict with the json built-in library. then you can iterate over the dict.

Answer (score 3):

This is JSON. You can convert it to a normal python dict using `json.loads(string)`, or in the case of `requests` there's a `.json()` shortcut:

```
data = requests.get(url).json()
nombres = data['nombres']
```

Comment: Getting this error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @PythonNLMB sounds like what you're getting with `requests` isn't what you showed us. Can you share the URL? If not, what if you `print(repr(requests.get(url).text))`?